# Jenkinsのgithub organizationジョブからmaven release-pluginを使う

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

下記を参照してJenkinsの`Github Organization`と`gitbucket`を連携しました。

https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-Multibranch-Pipeline-and-Organization

mavenのrelease-pluginでリリースできるようにしたコードをgitbucketにコミットするとJenkinsで下記のようなエラーとなります。

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project my-app: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.: Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref -> [Help 1]
```

jenkonsのログで確認したworkspaceで同じ操作をしてみると下記のようにエラーは再現できました。

```
bash-4.4# git branch -av | cat
* (HEAD detached from 675030f) f40b9c4 [maven-release-plugin] prepare release my-app-2.0
remotes/origin/test-chore    675030f scmupdate
bash-4.4# git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
bash-4.4#
```

下記にjenkinsの`git plugin`を使った場合に同様なエラーが出た場合のワークアラウンドがありますが、`github organization`での対処方法をご存知の方はいないでしょうか。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511390/jenkins-git-plugin-detached-head